# Error in Chemistry OpenCmis while getting root folder

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I am using chemistry opencmis version 0.13.0 to connect to alfresco repository.Below is the code snippet

```
    Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // user credentials
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, "admin");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, "admin");

    // connection settings
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmisatom");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());

    // set the alfresco object factory
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.OBJECT_FACTORY_CLASS, "org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl");

    // create session
    SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Session session = factory.getRepositories(parameter).get(0).createSession();
```

I am able to create a session but when the do the below operation

```
session.getRootFolder();
```

I am getting the below exception

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/TransientCmisObject
>       at org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl.convertObject(AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl.java:297)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getObject(SessionImpl.java:523)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getRootFolder(SessionImpl.java:735)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getRootFolder(SessionImpl.java:729)
>       at cmisops.CMISConnect.main(CMISConnect.java:60)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.TransientCmisObject
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 5 more

I am using chemistry-opencmis-client-api-0.13.0,chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-0.13.0,chemistry-opencmis-client-impl-0.13.0,chemistry-opencmis-commons-api-0.13.0,chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl-0.13.0,alfresco-opencmis-extension-0.3

I am using Alfresco enterprise 5.0 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this endpoint instead of the one you're using:

`http://<hostname>:<port>/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom`

and please refer to [this page](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/pra/1/concepts/cmis-bindings.html) to adress any cmis binding issue in alfresco.

---

**UPDATE :** The OP [solved the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217944/error-in-chemistry-opencmis-while-getting-root-folder/35219667#comment58154955_35219667) by [setting a repository id in his session parameters](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html#connecting-to-a-repository-by-id).

Comment: solved the issue by adding repository id as a parameter while setting up the session . Its working fine now.

Comment: @user2361591 Please be aware that the endpoint you are connected to is only available as legacy ressource and may be removed in the future

Comment: even if i use the url you gave me with my code minus the repository id it still gives me that error. So it seems repository id is mandatory

Comment: @user2361591 Yes, I can confirm that. Neverthless you should be using the new URL instead of the old one

Comment: Thanks Younes Regaieg